# Struts 2 interceptor redirect JSP page

Tags: redirect, struts2, interceptor, interceptorstack

Using Struts 2, I have this interceptor:

```java
public class AccessInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {
    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation ai) throws Exception {
        ActionContext actionContext = ai.getInvocationContext();
        Map<String, Object> session = actionContext.getSession();
        Boolean logged = (Boolean) session.get("logged");
        if(logged == null) {
          session.put("logged", false);
          logged = false;
        }
        if (!logged) {
            // If exception is here, it IS thrown, so I am sure "login" is returned on /homepage
            return "login";
        }   
        return ai.invoke();
    }
}
```

And this `struts.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<package name="loginInterceptor" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <interceptors> 
        <interceptor name="access"
         class="logininterceptor.interceptors.AccessInterceptor"/>
        <interceptor-stack name="appDefault"> 
            <interceptor-ref name="access" />
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" /> 
        </interceptor-stack> 
    </interceptors> 
    <default-interceptor-ref name="appDefault" />       
    <global-results>
        <result name="login">/WEB-INF/content/login.jsp</result>
    </global-results>
</package>
</struts>
```

I have also `/WEB-INF/content/homepage.jsp` JSP and `/WEB-INF/content/login.jsp` and `mypackage.LoginAction.java` class. There is not an acton class for homepage

The problem is, that when I go to the `/homepage` page, it is NOT redirected to `login.jsp` and I see the `homepage.jsp` content. What is wrong?

PS: I use struts2-convention-plugin

Comment: How do you access to that homepage? Theorically, you didn't have to have the permission to access to any jsp that  under the `/WEB-INF` folder of your application.

Comment: +1 Good question, which has to do with overriding conventions defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the conventions plugin uses the "convention-default" package which does not know about your interceptor or interceptor stack.

If you could create a package which extends conventions-default doing just what your interceptor stack does (defines the interceptor, interceptor stack and defines the default result type) and then make the conventions plugin apply that stack as the default for all actions wouldn't that be great? You can.

After the `<struts>` tag define a constant like so:

```
<constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="loginInterceptor"/>
```

The other suggestion, was to use struts.xml to override the conventions, which is fine but a little verbose.

Another option is to use the parent package annotation, which is good when you need to override the default behavior but as you pointed out you want *this* to be the default behavior so you should reserve annotations for overriding this, not to implement it.

It may be worth browsing the following list of struts2 conventions plugin constants for the future: http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8/docs/convention-plugin.html#ConventionPlugin-Overwritingpluginclasses

PS: Just naming preference but I would call your package login-package rather than loginInterceptor... not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force to execute the interceptor every time anyone is accessing to `homepage.jsp`, the correct way of doing this is to put an action that returns the jsp. For example:

```
<struts>
...
<package name="loginInterceptor" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <interceptors> 
        ...
    </interceptors> 
    <default-interceptor-ref name="appDefault" />       
    <global-results>
       ...
    </global-results>
    <action name="homepage">
        <result>/WEB-INF/content/homepage.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

After that, when a user tries to access to `http://.../homepage.action`, the interceptor will be executed and will be redirected to the login page if the user is not logged in.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. But what if I have many pages like homepage.jsp. If I add <action name="login" class="logininterceptor.action.LoginAction">
 <result>/WEB-INF/content/login.jsp</result>
</action><action name="*">
 <result>/WEB-INF/content/{1}.jsp</result>
</action> it ends with "Infinite recursion detected: [//homepage!execute, //login, //login]"

Comment: @Petr I believe that what you are asking is another question, it's difficult to answer that nicely with the limitations of the comments. Furthermore anyone that has more knowledge about wildcard mappings, will answer better than me that question.